# What is opinionated CSS when normalizing?

Tags: css

I can read on the [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) documentation that *"normalize.css is a CSS library that provides consistent, cross-browser default styling of HTML elements."*. The docs for [@csstools/normalize.css](https://github.com/csstools/normalize.css/) mentions that developers often opinionated styles. The documentation for @csstools/normalize.css also mentions that opinionated styles were deprecated and removed.

What are opinionated styles and when may I want to keep/remove them?

Comment: It explains it right there in the documentation you pointed to. _"“opinionated” styles — styles developers often prefer but which do not fix bugs or “normalize” browser differences."_

Comment: Hello @j08691, I am afraid that does not answer my question. What are opinionated styles and when may I want to keep/remove them?

Comment: I don't see how it doesn't answer your question, but OK. Plus, the repo you pointed two even has two explain "opinionated" files to look at as examples.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap is what might be considered an **opinionated** framework. In other words, it has ideas about layouts, and it makes you work extra hard if you want it to look/behave differently.

Consider the default CSS breakpoints for screen widths: a medium-sized screen for Bootstrap is one that starts at a device width of `768px`. And what if you want to target, say, the limit of `600px`? It’s the same with almost every other component in bootstrap: rows and containers have their default padding, buttons have colors and borders that are very tricky to override without a lot of work, and so on.

Comment: I understand what an opinionated framework is in that context, when may I want to keep/remove them when normalizing?

Comment: @Blunderchips Whenever you disagree with their use. That's the "opinion" part.